# top value from each group in scala

Tags: scala, sorting, grouping

I have an array of id and scores and I want to find top score for each id.

```
val idAndScore = Array(
    ("10022 10021", -6.1825),
    ("10022 10021", -6.477912),
    ("10022 10021", -7.207875),
    ("10022 10021", -6.251606),
    ("10022 10021", -6.343815),
    ("10022 10021", -6.62864),
    ("29920 29919", -9.134842),
    ("29920 29919", -9.049803),
    ("29920 29919", -9.658904),
    ("29920 29919", -9.186851),
    ("29920 29919", -8.525129),
    ("29920 29919", -9.46663),
    ("29920 29919", -8.496784),
    ("29920 29919", -9.2584),
    ("29946 29945", -10.010943),
    ("29946 29945", -8.588902),
    ("29946 29945", -8.915169),
    ("29946 29945", -8.538752)
)
```

and the required output is as fallows

```
(10022 10021,-6.1825)
(29920 29919,-8.496784)
(29946 29945,-8.538752)
```

I have tried

```
val top = idAndScore.groupBy { case (id, score) => id }
.flatMap(_._2.toList.sortBy { case (id, score) => score })
```

but it gives me

```
(29946 29945,-8.538752)
(29920 29919,-8.496784)
(10022 10021,-6.1825)
```

and adding reverse as fallows

```
val top = idAndScore.groupBy { case (id, score) => id }
.flatMap(_._2.toList.sortBy { case (id, score) => score }.reverse)
```

gives

```
(29946 29945,-10.010943)
(29920 29919,-9.658904)
(10022 10021,-7.207875)
```

I have been able to get the required output by using sort twice and reverse. But I think it would be possible in a more cleaner way. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: is input already sorted by id ?

Comment: No they are not. Sorry in this example they look like so.

Comment: Use `reduceByKey` not `groupByKey` for a speed up. As the doc for `groupByKey` says "Note: This operation may be very expensive. If you are grouping in order to perform an aggregation (such as a sum or average) over each key, using PairRDDFunctions.aggregateByKey or PairRDDFunctions.reduceByKey will provide much better performance."

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul Thanks but in this case we are not performing parallel spark rdd operations. This is serial scala.

Comment: @user3771345, Ah, OK! Normally the problem is the reverse - people posting questions that look like array ones but they're actually using Spark. However, a fold that just keeps track of the max might still be quicker than groupBy since that builds a list for each key where you're only interested in the max of that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly more efficient version as it just maintains the max, not the lists of values in order to take the max later.

```
idAndScore.foldLeft(Map[String, Double]() withDefaultValue Double.MinValue)
                   { case (m, (k, v)) => m updated (k, v max m(k))}
          .toSeq
          .sortBy{-_._2}

// Seq[(String, Double)] = ArrayBuffer((10022 10021,-6.1825),
                                       (29920 29919,-8.496784),
                                       (29946 29945,-8.538752))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
idAndScore.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.max).map(_._2).toList.sortBy(- _._2)
```

or

```
idAndScore.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.max).map(_._2).toList.sortBy { case (k, v) => -v }
```

Comment: Good this works. Can you explain sortBy(- _._2). To me it seems you are multiplying by -.

Comment: @user3771345 we need to sort by numeric values so we can negate them in order to get desired ordering, I've also updated my answer, HTH.